# Difference between 'contains' and 'containsKey' in Kotlin Map

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
val m = mapOf<String, Int>()
m.contains("Foo")
m.containsKey("Bar")
```

In Kotlin, there are two methods for `Map` to check whether the map has specified key: `contains` and `containsKey`

I know that `key in m` is the idiomatic way to check key existence, but I wonder why they have two methods doing same function. Do they have any differences between them? Or are they just some sort of legacy code for compatibility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is **no difference between these methods** in `Map`

`contains` is just generic function, used in different collections with different behaviour (Example: contains *object* in Collection, but *key* in Map)

`containsKey` and `containsValue` are `Map`s specific functions

But `contains` in `Map` is just a wrapper for `containsKey` [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt#L220):

```
public inline operator fun <@kotlin.internal.OnlyInputTypes K, V> Map<out K, V>.contains(key: K): Boolean = containsKey(key)
```

Answer (score 7):

They are equivalent. This is the `contains` [method implementation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt#L226):

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline operator fun <@kotlin.internal.OnlyInputTypes K, V> Map<out K, V>.contains(key: K): Boolean = containsKey(key)
```

According docs:

> This method (contains) allows to use the `x in map` syntax for checking whether
>   an object is contained in the map.